# Порядок вывода foreach

Tags: c#, .net, unity3d

Почему Foreach именно в таком порядке выводит объект?

- A
- B
- Q

```cs
using System.Collections; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using UnityEngine;

public class learningScript : MonoBehavior {   
 public Hashtable inventory = new Hashtable();

 void Start() {
  inventory.Add("age", "Q");
  inventory.Add("gender", "A");
  inventory.Add("name", "B");
  foreach (string invert in inventory.Keys) {
   Debug.Log(inventory[invert]);
  }   
 }

 void Update() {

 } 
}
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.collections.hashtable(v=vs.110).aspx -- в справке прямым текстом написано, что "Предоставляет коллекцию пар "ключ-значение", которые упорядочены по хэш-коду ключа. "

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Это не foreach выводит, это Hashtable хранит. Эта коллекция не сохраняет порядок элементов. List порядок сохранит, SortedDictionary отсортирует, а хэш-таблицы сохранят в труднопредсказуемом порядке. Если важны и исходный порядок, и быстрый индексированный доступ, можно хранить в двух коллекциях сразу.